# Big Picture from One Signal not shows up in Ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, onesignal, ionic-native

I tried add big picture in my push notification in Ionic from onesignal, the push notification is work well, but i didn't get the big picture that supposed to be there. I Already upload the image , is there any additional setting that i must add in my Ionic App to make it works ? Thanks

Comment: What was the image URL that you used? Was this on Android or iOS?

Comment: well actually i already get the image, but the image is hidden in notification so i need to expand the notification. Is there anyway to make the notification auto expand ? can we make new notification template ?